# Having "@" in username in credentials URL Basic authentication

Tags: api, encoding, base64, stripe-payments, urlencode

I'm trying to use Stripe webhook to call an API for pushing events to that API. And as in my understanding stripe has a way of adding basic authentication for webhooks by using https://{username}:{password}@myAPI.com which will then base64 encode Username and Password as Basic {based64encodedToken} to the endpoint https://myAPI.com

However, the username for basic authentication contains "@" in it, for example: user1@myapp-1awjn. Which will then mess up the API. Does anybody know how to escape it?

Comment: Why not using `AT_SIGN` to indicate '@'

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is  not a valid form of `userinfo` within the `authority` portion of a URI according to the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2).

> The user information, if present, is followed by a commercial
> at-sign ("@") that delimits it from the host.

If you need this, you'll need to URL encode the `@` and parse within your system, eg `https://user%40cool@example.com/`

Comment: Appreciate it!!